# Reputation in meta same as reputation in main site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

What does it mean here: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta when it says your reputation on meta is the same as your reputation on the main site because in my experience this is not the case.  Can some explain this to me or is it an error in the documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an error. Meta Stack Overflow is run as a fully fledge site, and is the Meta for both Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow. All other per site meta, ie. Meta Super User, is linked to the main site and user accounts are synchronised between the two. All sites have their own meta's, apart from Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Shouldn't the SO privilege page be different then?

Comment: @Micheal I think it needs to be edited to reflect the difference.

Comment: Could we add a form of this question and answer to the FAQ on the sites meta. I saw my reputation become the same on a site and its meta, I was wondering if I had gotten all those points from meta or if It was combined. Had to do a meta search... in SE:Meta! Found it in seconds, tho!

Comment: Is *Meta Stack Overflow* not the meta for all *Stack Exchange* sites?

Comment: @zyy Yes. Clearly the Stack Overflow Meta is just the meta for Stack Overflow. This is Stack Exchange Meta, the meta which is the meta for the entire community.

Answer (score 2):

This is true for all "child" metas in the network *except* for Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow.

Meta Stack Overflow server as both the meta for Stack Overflow, but also as the Meta for the entire network.  Due to this, it is not considered a "child" meta and its reputation is independent.

Comment: the text on http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta should reflect that, though